# Replace a substring if that substring is part of an array

Tags: javascript, python

I've written some code in Python, but I have to write it in JavaScript (for Google Apps Script). I would say I'm pretty bad at JS and can't seem to replicate what I've done in Python. 
Basically, I have a string, that might or not have a "/" or "-" in it, and if it does, I want for it to replace all substrings that match 2 specific arrays by "".

(For context, whitelistdias and whitelistmes are 2 arrays with several words in them)

```
 var whitelistdias = ["terça-feira", "quarta-feira",
                     "quinta-feira", "sexta-feira", "sábado", "domingo",
                     "segunda", "terça", "quarta", "quinta", "sexta", "sabado",
                     "terca"];

  var whitelistmes = ["janeiro", "fevereiro", "março", "abril", "maio", "junho",
                    "julho", "agosto", "setembro", "outubro", "novembro",
                    "dezembro", "jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun",
                    "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez"];
```

The Python code I use for this is posted below:

```
    idk = str(idk)
    if "/" in idk or "-" in idk:
        for i in whitelistmes:
            if i in idk:
                mes = i
                idk = idk.replace(i, "")

        for i in whitelistdias:
            if i in idk:
                idk = str(idk)
                idk = idk.replace(i, "")
```

Example:

Basically let's say the string is 'Monday, 2nd October, 23:59'. I want to test if the string has a "/" or "-" and if so, replace "Monday" and "October" by "". The end result would be ",2nd 23:59"

Sorry if this seems trivial, but I really can't find a way to do it, and have searched for similar solutions to no avail.

Comment: have you actually made an attempt at it in JavaScript? If so please show it, it might not be hard to fix

Comment: P.S. Don't ask two questions in the same post, you run the risk of the post being closed as "too broad". Create it as a separate post instead. Thanks.

Comment: You want to replace "/" from '02/10/2019, 23:59' so it becomes '02102019, 23:59'? and same for '-'? Also you have them both in an array?

Comment: @ADyson just did that, thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @weegee no, not really. Basically let's say the string is 'Monday, 2nd October, 23:59'. I want to test if the string has a "/" or "-" and if so, replace "Monday" and "October" by "". The end result would be ",2nd 23:59"

Comment: @GabrielLeal what are these `supposed to conatin whitelistmes` and `whitelistdias`?

Comment: @fiveelements just edited the post with that information, thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we check if the string contains "/" or "-" by using [`string.protoype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) and then create an array which contains the things you want to replace. For each over that array and replace strings one by one.

```js
let str = "Monday, 2nd October, 23:59 -" // it contains "-"
let thingsToReplace = ["Monday", "October"]
if (str.includes("/") || str.includes("-")) { // || this means that if any of them is true then returns true
  thingsToReplace.forEach((strs) => { // for each the array and replace every string
    str = str.replace(strs, ""); // replace the string via string.replace(what to replace, and with what)
  })
}
console.log(str) // log it so we can see
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you so much! Sorry if my problem sounded confusing or was badly explained, I'm new to this :)

Comment: Adding an example always help. Next time when you post a question, be sure to include a [mcve] shortcode and specific/relevant to the problem. Include examples always. @GabrielLeal

Answer (score 2):

If anyone interested in a shorter solution by regex:

```js
let idk = "Monday, 2nd - October, 23:59";
let whitelist = ["Monday", "October"];
let regstr = new RegExp(whitelist.join('|'),'g');

// just to show the replace code and ignore '/' and '-' check
idk = idk.replace(regstr,'');

console.log(idk);
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

- For the existence of a substring in a string you may use `indexOf()` or `includes()`
- For iteration use `for loop` or `forEach`
- For replacement the function is the same: `replace()`

Here is the running code:

```js
idk = "Monday, 2nd - October, 23:59";
whitelistmes = ["January", "October"];
whitelistdias = ["Tuesday", "Monday"];
if (idk.indexOf("/") != -1 || idk.indexOf("-") != -1) {
    for (i in whitelistmes) {
        if (idk.indexOf(whitelistmes[i]) != -1) {
            //mes = i
            idk = idk.replace(whitelistmes[i], "");
        }
    }

    for (i in whitelistdias) {
        if (idk.indexOf(whitelistdias[i]) != -1) {
            //idk = str(idk)
            idk = idk.replace(whitelistdias[i], "");
        }
    }
}
console.log(idk);
```

The above version replicates your code. Here goes the better version:

```js
idk = "Monday, 2nd - October, 23:59";
whitelistmes = ["January", "October"];
whitelistdias = ["Tuesday", "Monday"];
if (idk.includes("/") || idk.includes("-")) {
    [...whitelistmes].forEach(token => {
        if (idk.includes(token)) {
            idk = idk.replace(token, "");
        }
    });

    [...whitelistdias].forEach(token => {
        if (idk.includes(token)) {
            idk = idk.replace(token, "");
        }
    });
}
console.log(idk);
```

Please note, you may combine `whitelistmes` and `whitelistdias` into one as well since the action taken is same for both.